# In Nodejs, if you call the cb first, then will this cause the rest of the function to execute?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose I have

```
function foo(cb) {
  cb()
}

function bar() {
  foo(function() {});
}

function zee(cb) {
  bar()
  cb()
}
```

If I call zee, will the call to zee cb wait for bar's foo cb to execute?

Comment: Yes, as long as it is called synchronously. but then.... what would you need callbacks for.

Comment: @KevinB - Given how often Node uses callbacks to handle asynchronous events, I imagine beginners could easily come under the impression that callbacks are always called asynchronously.

Comment: well, they should be in my opinion. even if the work being done can be accomplished synchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - unless you use any asynchronous code (like `setTimeout`, AJAX requests or Promises), your program will step through the calls one by one.

```
zee(cb1)
    bar()
        foo(cb2)
            cb2()
    cb1()
```

Note that this isn't specific to Node, this is just how JavaScript works in general.